# copy past from ms word to WordPress issue

Tags: php, wordpress, ms-word, copy-paste

When I copy content from an MS Word file to the WordPress editor, decimal point numbers are not being pasted properly, for example

Content in the word file (font Calibri):

> • Number of abc at 5.83 crores.

Content after paste in WordPress editor (font Georgia):

> • Number of abc at 83 crores.

No matter what font I use, the result is always the same.

This is happening only with the first occurrence of the decimal value. If I have sentence like:

> • Number of abc at 5.83 crores and 8.45 crores.

The result is:

> • Number of abc at 83 crores and 8.45 crores.

I have also noticed that this issue is with Bullet list only. Editor used in WP is TinyMCE default editor.

Comment: Are you pasting the content on _Code_ tab or on the _Visual_ tab?

Comment: @AlexandreAimbiré i am doing it on visual tab.

Comment: Have you tried pasting the contents on the _Code_ tab? Doing so "clears" any previous styling from wherever you`re copying from and may resolve your issue.

Comment: Gentle folk, this question is off-topic on Stack Overflow - it's not a programming question. Could you discuss it elsewhere? (In chat, if either of you has enough reputation points to open a chat.)

Answer (score 0):

MS Word uses Rich Text Formatting so to resolve your issue with copy/paste into WordPress simply right click and select Paste as plain text.